# gganimate is not keeping all the past marks when using shadow_mark option

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am plotting earthquakes and I want to show how the earthquake locations evolve over time. I only want to see the earthquake location points plotted as the time moves forward, and not a moving point between earthquake locations (as it appears to be happening).

These are the data:

```
clust <- data.frame(latitude = c(31.61205, 31.6132, 31.61286, 31.61355, 
31.61087, 31.6141, 31.61514, 31.6132, 31.61118, 31.61511, 31.61409, 
31.61409, 31.61307, 31.618, 31.60965, 31.61007, 31.60884, 31.60905, 
31.6094, 31.60816, 31.61068, 31.61006, 31.60837, 31.61254, 31.60817, 
31.61333, 31.60954, 31.61123, 31.61157, 31.60904, 31.60845), 
    longitude = c(-104.53083, -104.52606, -104.52635, -104.5249, 
    -104.53191, -104.52602, -104.52617, -104.52593, -104.5309, 
    -104.52869, -104.52988, -104.52938, -104.52963, -104.52836, 
    -104.53803, -104.53386, -104.53954, -104.5379, -104.53699, 
    -104.54104, -104.53371, -104.53538, -104.54168, -104.52697, 
    -104.54457, -104.53882, -104.53805, -104.53255, -104.52933, 
    -104.54067, -104.54229), depth = c(7.589, 7.295, 7.387, 7.282, 
    7.454, 7.76, 7.787, 7.282, 7.675, 6.003, 6.077, 6.126, 6.218, 
    7.494, 7.026, 7.59, 7.623, 7.545, 7.287, 7.693, 7.169, 7.423, 
    7.65, 7.066, 7.137, 8.316, 7.129, 7.41, 7.477, 7.115, 7.16
    ), mag = c(3.12, 2.64, 2.5, 2.34, 2.63, 1.44, 1.47, 2.27, 
    2.28, 2.14, 2.31, 2.26, 2.2, 2.04, 2.32, 2.12, 2.6, 2.16, 
    3.02, 2.04, 3.31, 2.28, 2.1, 2.26, 2.74, 2, 2.01, 2.83, 2.12, 
    2.25, 2.46), cluster = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L
    ), datetime = structure(c(1648096488, 1648154064, 1648223479, 
    1648458486, 1648597348, 1650278472, 1650281886, 1653753093, 
    1653814043, 1655618186, 1658076718, 1658093072, 1659482037, 
    1662994538, 1669204899, 1669779205, 1670032484, 1670032691, 
    1670071292, 1670077497, 1670088406, 1670093402, 1670131993, 
    1670147329, 1670688840, 1670766002, 1670942474, 1672311253, 
    1672366539, 1679225056, 1679256690), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"))
```

Here is my code:

```
anim <- ggplot(clust , aes(x = longitude, y=latitude, size = mag, colour = '#562486')) +
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") + 
  transition_time(clust$datetime) +
  labs(title = "{frame_time}") +
  shadow_mark(past = TRUE, future = FALSE, alpha = 0.5) 

animate(anim,  height = 4, width = 7, units = "in", fps = 0.5, end_pause = 60, res = 100) #+ gifski_renderer()
```

[image]

I have tried `transition_events(start = datetime)` instead of `transition_time(clust$datetime)`, but I don't understand the options well enough so that is giving me errors. I have also tried adjusting shadow_mark options for wake_length, but I am not sure if there are other options that I am unaware of.

Comment: If I run the code you provided, I do not get the same output. What version of `gganimate` did you use? I tested with `gganimate_1.0.8` and `ggplot2_3.5.0`

Comment: @MrFlick I am getting the same results with `gganimate_1.0.9` and `ggplot2_3.5.0`. What's the difference between your output and what OP provided, if I may ask?

Comment: @M-- For me, the point doesn't move/travel. They each just reveal themselves in time.

Comment: @MrFlick have you tried it with ```gifski_renderer()```? Anyway, I am gonna delete my answer, without `gifski`, I also don't get the move, they just appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `group = datetime`:

(I increased the `fps` just for the reprex.)

```r
library(gganimate)

anim <- 
  ggplot(clust, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, size = mag, group = datetime)) +
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 0.7, colour = '#562486') +
  theme_bw() +
  transition_time(datetime) +
  labs(title = "{format(frame_time, '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S')}", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  shadow_mark(past = TRUE, future = FALSE, alpha = 0.5) 

animate(anim,  height = 4, width = 7, units = "in", fps = 5, end_pause = 0, res = 100)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-29 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>